# Dataframe rows and column calling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I don't understand the error in the picture. Is this the correct ways to acess rows? Then how do you acess columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you need `.loc` for accessing, something like below:

```
df.loc['Row 1']
```

You can view details in [documentation of loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).